# How do I exit from dash -n?

Tags: unity-dash

I've connected to an Ubuntu machine using SSH.

According to [DashAsBinSh on Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) [dash](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dash) is used in place of [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) by default.

The article says

> You can use dash -n to check that a script will run under dash without actually running it

Apparently the `-n` means **noexec**. Out of shear curiosity, I ran the command `dash -n`.

I was greeted with a prompt that I could not exit.

```
user@remote:~$ dash -n
$ exit
$ exit;
$ quit
$ --help
$ help
$ ^C
$
```

How do I abort what I'm doing and return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> (which should be equivalent to passing an `exit` command to the shell) instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Comment: I must have tried most Ctrl combinations except this one. Thanks!